# not looping when in interval

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some html which looks like this:

```
           <li *ngFor="#item of items; #i=index" >
            <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
            </li>
```

I then want to populate the list every one second, so I have something like this:

```
let t=setInterval(() =>{
                this.items  = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"];
            },1000);
```

I know looking at this it looks like why are you running an interval the value is the same. I have other logic in my code which has if and else statements that will break the interval, but I am not getting any items displaying at all and that is my concern. I expect the 9 items to be in a list on my html page, but none of them display. If I remove the interval then it displays the items. So if it is inside the interval it does not display, how can I make it so it does? I am unsure of the problem.

Comment: `() =>{ this.items  = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"]; }` looks like a function, in original JavaScript, setInterval requires function name instead of function itself as its first parameter. `setInterval(function(),1000)` will only run once. `setInterval(function,1000)` is the correct way.

Comment: Make sure `setInterval` and its callback are actually executed.

Comment: I have tried instead creating function, putting the logic in there and putting function name instead in the interval, but it still does not work. If I put console.log('loop running') inside of the function it is being printed every 1 second so it is being called.

Answer (score 2):

A more "Angular 2 way" of approaching this would be to use [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in conjunction with an Observable and the `Observable.timer` operator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  pipes: [AsyncPipe], //import this from angular2/common
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#item of (items | async); #i=index" >
        <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
class YourComponent {
   items: Observable<string[]>; 

   constructor(){
       this.items = Observable.timer(0, 1000) //emit after 0 ms, then every 1000ms 
                              .map(()=>{
                                  //insert real business logic
                                  return  ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"]
                               })
   }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running. I tried inserting also a console.log statement right before the return to see if it is firing, but nothing is being printed.

Comment: What's in the console?

Comment: Please post a plunkr reproducing this.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

ChangeDefectorRef did it for me. Adding `this.ref.markForCheck();` inside of the interval refreshed the items for me and it now displays.